# Send array data to another page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to send the data to another page using javascript. I will using a "next" button with Onclick function. I want that when I click that button all data in textboxes on this page is send to be displayed on another page using javascript.

```
<table border="1" id="bill_table" width="50%" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="5">
    <tr style="display:none;">
        <td class="style2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="style2">
            <div id="name_div">
                <input name="item[]" type="text" id="item" size="20" style="width:100px;"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="style2">
            <input name="job[]" type="text" id="job" size="20" style="width:100px;"/>
        </td>
        <td class="style2">
            <div id="relation_div">
                <input name="rate[]" type="text" id="rate" size="20" style="width:100px;"/>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="style2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style2">SNo</td>
        <td class="style2">Item</td>
        <td class="style2">Job Charges</td>
        <td class="style2">Rate</td>
        <td class="style2">
            <input name="add_button" type="button" id="add_button" size="20" value="Add" style="width:50px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p align="center">
    <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</p>
```

and javascript i m curently using:-

```
var itemCount = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var objs = [];
  var temp_objs = [];
  $("#add_button").click(function() {
    var html = "";

    var obj = {
      "ROW_ID": itemCount,
      "Item": $("#item").val(),
      "JOB": $("#job").val(),
      "Rate": $("#rate").val(),
    }

    $("#item").val('');
    $("#job").val('');
    $("#rate").val('');

    // add object
    objs.push(obj);
    itemCount++;

    // dynamically create rows in the table
    html = "<tr id='tr" +
      itemCount + "'>" + "<td>" +
      itemCount + "</td>" +
      "<td><INPUT type='text' name='txt1[]' readonly  value='" +
      obj['Item'] + "'/></td>" +
      "<td><INPUT type='text' name='txt2[]' readonly  value='" +
      obj['JOB'] + "'/></td>" +
      "<td><INPUT type='text' readonly    name='txt3[]' value='" +
      obj['Rate'] + "'/></td>" +
      "<td><input type='button'  id='" +
      itemCount +
      "' value='remove'>" +
      "</td> </tr>";

    //add to the table
    $("#bill_table").append(
        html)

      // The remove button click
    $("#" + itemCount).click(
      function() {
        var buttonId = $(this)
          .attr("id");

        //write the logic for removing from the array
        $("#tr" + buttonId).remove();
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Is the "next page" on a different url, or is it generated using JavaScript?

Comment: @BillyNate Different url

Comment: I'd go with Alex's answer. If you are fine with the get parameters in the url of your next page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Jquery serialize function and redirect to next page, like this

```
 $("form").serialize()
```

For example your form contains this

```
 <form action="">
   First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
   Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
</form>
```

So after serialization you will get

```
 FirstName=Mickey&LastName=Mouse
```

And then use window.location like this

```
 window.location="youNextPage.html?"+YourSerializedData
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a form and revieve the data through php on the next page.

```
<form action="your_file.php" method="post">
```

on the next page

```
var javaScriptVariable = "<?php echo $_POST['yourInputId'] ?>";
```

Comment: Right idea, but the OP isn't using PHP. Change the form action to a GET and they can read the querystring using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Don't use submit button for this logic, which will make your browser load a fresh page

I would recomend using single paged architecture (SPA) and client side template engine, my favourite is EJS http://www.embeddedjs.com/

Similar to php and jsp you can use <% %> and <%= %> and pass values to the tamplete.

Assume template.ejs

```
<tr id='tr<%=itemCount%>'>
 <td><%=itemCount%></td>
 <td><INPUT type='text' name='txt1[]' readonly  value='<%=obj['Item']%>'/></td>
 <td><INPUT type='text' name='txt2[]' readonly  value='<%=obj['JOB']%>'/></td>
 <td><INPUT type='text' readonly name='txt3[]' value='<%=obj['Rate']%>'/></td>
 <td><input type='button'  id='<%=itemCount%>' value='remove'></td>
</tr>
```

Use EJS as

```
var html = new EJS({url: 'template.ejs'}).render({"itemCount":itemCount, "obj":obj});
$("#bill_table").append(html)
```

You need to use some temporary server in your localhost for testing, like apache or xmpp or wamp or any other available

Answer (score 0):

Try using `localStorage.setItem()` and `.getItem()`, as it is simpler.